Approximate identity consisting of projections in a hereditary subalgebra
Why are the following two statements equivalent for a C*-algebra $A$ (assume it is unital if it helps) and a hereditary subalgebra $B$:

$B$ has a (not necessarily increasing) approximate identity consisting of projections.
For any $b_1,\dots,b_n$ in $B$ and $0<\epsilon<1$, there exists a projection $p\in B$ such that $||b_k(1-p)||<\epsilon$ for $1\leq k\leq n$.

Davidson in his book '$C^\ast$-algebras by example', in Theorem V.7.3 uses this to prove that every hereditary subalgebra of a real rank zero $C^\ast$-algebra has an approximate identity of projections. But he provides no justification as to why the above two statements are equivalent. In Brown and Pederson's paper on RR=0 $C^\ast$-algebras, they pass the proof to Proposition 14 of Pederson's paper 'Linear span of projections'. There the proof is passed to Theorem 3.1 of Elliott's paper 'Automorphisms determined by multipliers on ideal of a $C^\ast$-algebra' where the equivalence of the above statements is in turn passed to Theorem 1.5(iii) of Dixmier's paper 'On some $C^\ast$-algebras considered by Glimm' which I just don't understand.
Bonus question: is there a proof for the equivalence of RR=0 and hereditary subalgebra property for non-unital $C^\ast$-algebras? Thanks!

This is nearly just definition and has nothing to do with hereditary subalgebras: From $1$ to $2$, if $B$ has an approximate identity $(p_i)_i$ consisting of projections, $b_1, \cdots, b_n \in B$, and $0 < \epsilon < 1$, then for each $1 \leq k \leq n$, by definition of approximate identity, there is an $i_k$ s.t. whenever $i \geq i_k$, we have $\|b_k(1 - p_i)\| < \epsilon$. Pick any $i$ s.t. $i \geq i_k$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$. Then $p = p_i$ satisfies the required condition.
From $2$ to $1$, let $I$ be the net consisting of $(F, \epsilon)$ where $F$ ranges over finite subsets of $B$ and $\epsilon$ ranges over $(0, 1)$, ordered by $(F_1, \epsilon_1) \leq (F_2, \epsilon_2)$ iff $F_1 \subset F_2$ and $\epsilon_1 \geq \epsilon_2$. Then for each $i = (F, \epsilon) \in I$, by assumption we have a projection $p_i \in B$ s.t. $\|b(1 - p)\| < \epsilon$ for all $b \in F$. Then $(p_i)_{i \in I}$ is a net of projections s.t. $\lim_i bp_i = b$ for all $b \in B$. Taking conjugates shows $\lim_i p_ib = b$ for all $b \in B$ as well, so $(p_i)_{i \in I}$ is an approximate identity.

This is a quite standard trick in topology and analysis, going between a condition holding approximately for each finite set and up to some $\epsilon$ (or up to some open neighborhood, if we're working with a general topological space without a metric), and a net that makes the condition hold exactly for every element under taking limits.

Thank you! I don't know why I didn't realise this before.
